# How can I delete a specific line from a text file using C++?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, fstream

This is my text file content.

```
1
2
3
```

I want to delete a line in that file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
std::fstream file("havai.txt", ios::app | ios::in | ios::out);

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    int number;
    std::cout << "Enter the number: ";
    std::cin >> number;
    while (file.good())
    {
        getline(file, line);
        if (std::to_string(number) == line)
        {
            // How can I delete that line of my text file?
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I delete that line in the *if* statement?

Comment: Side note: `while (file.good())` tests that the stream is good before reading. The result of `getline(file, line);` is untested and could have failed resulting in bad behaviour at `if (std::to_string(number) == line)`. Use `while (getline(file, line))` instead. In general you need to read, test, and then use or handle error. Any other order is a bug.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing data from a file is far more complicated than it appears. It is almost always orders of magnitude easier to create a new file and write the information to be kept into it.

1. Open File A for reading.
2. Open File B for writing.
3. For each line in File A: If it's not a line to be discarded, write it to File B.
4. Close File A
5. Close File B
6. Replace File A with File B.